# Сравнение версий программы

Tags: swift

Пытаюсь реализовать сравнение версий программы,все работает, но при выходе за границы Int работать перестает, насколько я понимаю, при использовании .numeric просто берется часть числа в границах какого-то типа(думаю, что int) и сравнивается. Нужно либо приведение к типу вмещающему большие числа в каком-то виде и его использование с .numeric, либо другие варианты сравнения. Прошу помощи.

```
func versionFormatting(version:inout String) {
    version = String(version
        .unicodeScalars
        .filter(CharacterSet
        .decimalDigits
        .union(CharacterSet(charactersIn: "."))
        .contains))
    if version[version.startIndex] == "."  {
        version.insert("0", at: version.startIndex)
    }
    if version[version.index(before: version.endIndex)] == "."  {
        version.insert("0", at: version.endIndex)
    }
    version = version.replacingOccurrences(of: "..", with: ".0.")
    version = version.replacingOccurrences(of: "..", with: ".0.")
}

func compareVersions(first: String, second: String) -> Int {
    let firstVersion = first.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let secondVersion = second.components(separatedBy: ".")
    let collectiveCount = min(firstVersion.count, secondVersion.count);
    for i in 0..<collectiveCount {
        if firstVersion[i].compare(secondVersion[i], options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return 0
        }
        else if secondVersion[i].compare(firstVersion[i], options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return 1
        }
    }
    let maxLengthArray: [String]
    let versionIndex: Int
    if firstVersion.count == collectiveCount {
        maxLengthArray = secondVersion
        versionIndex = 1
    }
    else {
        maxLengthArray = firstVersion
        versionIndex = 0
    }
    for i in collectiveCount..<maxLengthArray.count {
        if maxLengthArray[i].compare("0", options: .numeric) == .orderedDescending {
            return versionIndex
        }
    }
    return -1
}

//print ("First version: ")
//var firstVersion = readLine()!
var firstVersion = "3479023749023749023790479023749023790479023749023790470.343243443424234.3423423423423894238946892364896238946892364892368946246"
//print ("Second version: ")
//var secondVersion = readLine()!
var secondVersion = "3479023749023749023790479023749023790479023749023790470.53243443424234.3423423423423894238946892364896238946892364892368946246"

versionFormatting(version:&firstVersion)
versionFormatting(version:&secondVersion)

print(firstVersion)
print(secondVersion)

var result = compareVersions(first:firstVersion, second:secondVersion)
if result == -1 {
    print("версии равны")
}
else if result == 0 {
    print("первая версия актуальнее")
}
else {
    print("вторая версия актуальнее")
}
```

Comment: Если кому интересно, то versionFormatting добавляет нули между точками и до, и после точек, если это необходимо.

Comment: Я конечно извиняюсь, но для чего могут понадобиться такие цифры в _версии программы_? Задел на ближайшую пару тысяч лет? Может быть просто ограничить диапазон принимаемых значений?

Comment: @schmidt9 просто по заданию так нужно)

Answer (score 0):

Swift не поддерживает работу с настолько большими числами "из коробки". Как вариант нужно либо писать свою реализацию, либо накладывать ограничения на допустимые значения (например `Int.max`), либо использовать стороннее решение.

Я бы предложил воспользоваться последним вариантом - библиотекой [Swift-BigInt](https://github.com/mkrd/Swift-BigInt), хотя в данном случае это и похоже на стрельбу из пушки по воробьям.

```
    func compareVersions(first: String, second: String) -> Int {

        let firstVersion = first.components(separatedBy: ".").map {
            return BInt($0)
        }
        let secondVersion = second.components(separatedBy: ".").map {
            return BInt($0)
        }

        let collectiveCount = min(firstVersion.count, secondVersion.count);

        for i in 0..<collectiveCount {

            guard let v1 = firstVersion[i], let v2 = secondVersion[i] else {
                return -1
            }

            if v1 > v2 {
                return 0
            } else if v1 < v2 {
                return 1
            }
        }

        let maxLengthArray: [BInt?]
        let versionIndex: Int

        if firstVersion.count == collectiveCount {
            maxLengthArray = secondVersion
            versionIndex = 1
        } else {
            maxLengthArray = firstVersion
            versionIndex = 0
        }

        for i in collectiveCount..<maxLengthArray.count {
            if let value = maxLengthArray[i], value > BInt(0) {
                return versionIndex
            }
        }

        return -1
    }
```

Вывод

> первая версия актуальнее

Comment: Мне подходит первый вариант, но я пишу на swift впервые, поэтому не знаю, как это сделать)

Comment: В таком случае можете посмотреть как это сделано в указанной мною библиотеке